# PySpark Dict Lookup - TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a **PySpark** dataframe "df_data" that looks like this:

| Name | Country ID |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 1 |
| Tim | 3 |

Now, I have another data frame "df_lookup" that holds information to the numeric value for which I want to perform a lookup and append a column to the "df_data":

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Greece |
| 3 | USA |

For this purpose I already converted the "df_lookup" into a dictionary:

```
lookup_dict = {row.asDict()["ID"] : row.asDict()["Country"] for row in df_lookup.collect()}
```

That results in a dictionary which looks like this:

```
{'1': 'Greece',
 '2': 'USA'}
```

Now, I would like to define a lookup expression and add the new column as part of that to the "df_data":

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit    

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in lookup_dict.keys()], [lit(x) for x in lookup_dict.values()])

data_new = df_data.withColumn("Country Name", mapping_expr[col("Country ID")])
```

However, when trying to define the mapping expression, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [Column, Column, Column, Column, Column, Column, Column, Column, Column, Column, Column] of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Comment: If you have 2 dataframes that you want to merge data, you can use `join`. `df_data.join(df_lookup, on=(df_data['Country ID'] == df_lookup['ID']), how='inner')` `inner` could be `left` if you have missing lookup. There are a couple of similar questions about `join`, so if this helps, you can close the post.

here is some ref about join: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/